# Grep specific text from log

Tags: sed, grep

I try to figure it out how can grep in linux only the "SIG:" hash part from that log below:

```
20120927:10:57:23|89252871|3342|ESP individual score details for Message ID: <esp:msgid> -|<RBL:<0>  SHA:<0>  SHA_FLAGS:<0>  UHA:<12>  ISC:<0>  BAYES:<0>  SenderID:<0>  DKIM:<0>  TS:<-1>  SIG:<309875857436-4372-986476-327698-7436-984376-43276-98437643-8276-84327-6743-6874-986-86743-86732-867432-687432-687>  DSC:<0>  ('TRU_spam1', 47):<0> ('TRU_legal_spam', 31):<0> ('TRU_marketing_spam', 34):<0> ('TRU_profanity_spam', 39):<0> ('TRU_medical_spam', 35):<0> ('TRU_playsites', 46):<0> ('TRU_money_spam', 37):<0> ('TRU_stock_spam', 41):<0> ('TRU_embedded_image_spam', 27):<0> ('TRU_urllinks', 49):<0> ('TRU_watch_spam', 42):<0> ('TRU_phish_spam', 38):<0> ('TRU_spam2', 48):<0> ('TRU_misc_spam', 36):<0> ('TRU_LOREAL', 55):<0> ('TRU_freehosting', 45):<0> ('TRU_lotto_spam', 32):<0> ('TRU_ru_spamsubj', 56):<0> ('TRU_adult_spam', 18):<0> ('URL Real-Time Signatures', 9):<0> ('TRU_scam_spam', 40):<0>:89252871>|
```

Final view:

```
309875857436-4372-986476-327698-7436-984376-43276-98437643-8276-84327-6743-6874-986-86743-86732-867432-687432-687
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Perl regex (works on GNU grep):

```
grep -oP '(?<=SIG:<)[^>]*(?=>)'
```

Comment: Is it possible to insert new line after every results

Comment: Yep, I find the solution:
`grep -oP '(?<=SIG:<)[^>]*(?=>)'|sed -e "s/^.*$/&1\n/"`

Comment: @KalinBorisov Or you can do `| sed 'i \ '`

Answer (score 2):

`grep` alone cannot help you much here. You can add `cut` to your toolbox:

```
grep -o 'SIG:<[^>]\+' | cut -f2 -d\<
```

First, select SIG and everything following it up to a `>`. Then, only return what's after the first `<`.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed 's/.*SIG:<\([^>]\+\)>.*/\1/g' INPUTFILE
```

Might work for you

Comment: In my first try's i use similar code but without success, this code not work just print whole information.

Comment: Zsolt, I tink you have a typo: there are two closing `>`s. I think you need to remove the one from inside the parenthesis.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i~/SIG:/){gsub("SIG:<","",$i);gsub(">","",$i);print $i;break}}' your_file
```

Comment: When I use that and SIG have spaces this command print only information to the first space then interrupt.

Answer (score 1):

Use two greps, one to grab the right field, and one clean up:

```
<infile grep -o 'SIG:<[^>]*' | grep -o '[^<]*$'
```